# How to Pass self reference from ActorSystem in Akka Typed

Tags: scala, akka

I am trying to get replies from the AKKA actor but i am able to get response with the Help of Ask method

```
object mainTest {

  val TestTypedSystem: ActorSystem[FuncTest.TypedFuncTest] = ActorSystem(FuncTest(),"FuncTest")

  implicit val sc: Scheduler = TestTypedSystem.scheduler

  implicit val ex: ExecutionContext = TestTypedSystem.executionContext

  import scala.concurrent.duration._

  import scala.language.postfixOps
  implicit val timeout: Timeout = Timeout(3 seconds)

  import FuncTest._

  //passing actorContext to the immutable Case class directly

  val testList = List (
    AskSomeoneTyped("Jay", 32, 'c',ActorRef[FuncTest.TypedFuncTest]),
    AskSomeoneTyped("Jay1", 32, 'a',ActorRef[FuncTest.TypedFuncTest]),
    AskSomeoneTyped("Jay2", 32, 'b',ActorRef[FuncTest.TypedFuncTest])
  )

  testList.foreach {
    player => TestTypedSystem ! TestaddSomeone(player)
  }

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

 //Ask pattern to get responses by passing self context

 val sendingResp = TestTypedSystem.ask{
    f: ActorRef[FuncTest.TypedFuncTest] => AskSomeoneTyped("Jay",32,'c',f)
 }


  sendingResp.onComplete{
    case Success(value) => TestTypedSystem.log.info(s"Successfully completed : $value")
    case Failure(exception) => TestTypedSystem.log.warn(s"Got an exception $exception")

    }
  }
}
```

above Ask pattern from main method helps me get results back by passing 1 arg at a time but when using list.foreach I am not able to pass context of ActorSystem to get responses for a List of Actors.

messages are going to DeadLetters

Any Suggestions?

Comment: could you add the definitions of AskSomeoneTyped and TestaddSomeone

Comment: sealed trait TypedFuncTest
    
        final case class AskSomeoneTyped(name: String, Age: Int, grade: Char, replyTo: ActorRef[TypedFuncTest]) extends TypedFuncTest
    
    final case class TestaddSomeone(askSomeone: AskSomeoneTyped) extends TypedFuncTest`enter code here`

Answer (score 0):

Still a lot of the code is missing, so I can't verify my answer. However, an educated guess would be:

The fourth argument of the each of the three case class instances in the list

```
val testList = List (
    AskSomeoneTyped("Jay", 32, 'c',ActorRef[FuncTest.TypedFuncTest]),
    AskSomeoneTyped("Jay1", 32, 'a',ActorRef[FuncTest.TypedFuncTest]),
    AskSomeoneTyped("Jay2", 32, 'b',ActorRef[FuncTest.TypedFuncTest])
  )
```

reference the *type* of the actor reference, *not* the actual actor references.
If the behavior of `FuncTest.apply()`  (missing in the above) tries to send a reply to these 'references', none will arive.

The problem is that the maintest object is not an actor, thus has no actor reference. Akka is not able to send it messages. Hence the `f` in the ask pattern

```
val sendingResp = TestTypedSystem.ask{
    f: ActorRef[FuncTest.TypedFuncTest] => AskSomeoneTyped("Jay",32,'c',f)
 }
```

which provides this reference. See [the docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/from-classic.html#ask).

You might want to try something more along these lines:

```
case class Someone( name: String, age: Int, grade: Char)

val people = List (
    Someone("Jay",  32, 'c'),
    Someone("Jay1", 32, 'a'),
    Someone("Jay2", 32, 'b')
)

people.map{
    case Someone( name, age, grade ) => TestTypedSystem.ask( actorRef => AskSomeoneTyped( name, age, grade, actorRef ))
}.foreach( _.onComplete
{
    case Success(value) => TestTypedSystem.log.info(s"Successfully completed : $value")
    case Failure(exception) => TestTypedSystem.log.warn(s"Got an exception $exception")
})
```

Hope this helps.